# How can shared_ptr offer noexcept assignment?

Tags: c++

How can `std::shared_ptr` offer a `noexcept` `operator=`? Surely, if this `shared_ptr` is the last one, then it will have to destroy its contents, and it can't guarantee that the destructor of that object does not throw, or the custom deleter used originally does not throw.

Comment: It's interesting that its own destructor is not `noexcept`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and that `operator=` is defined to call the destructor (since it creates a temporary `shared_ptr`). I don't suppose there's a catch-all statement somewhere in the standard about which library destructors throw?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Been trying to find one, but no joy so far

Comment: I've left a note for litb to come and save the day.

Comment: I'm really not getting the point... operator= is supposed to share/augment the ownership of an object. How would this incur any destructor being called? The noexcept is for the assignment operation only, not for the targeted shared_ptr being assigned.

Comment: @Chico - It might be that the old value of the assigned to shared_ptr is the last pointer to some object. Then that object has to be destroyed.

Comment: @BoPersson now I got it =D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As I understand it, it's destructor will be implicitly `noexcept`.  And (at least with gcc 4.9.2) `std::is_nothrow_destructible<std::shared_ptr<int>>::value` evaluates to true, which seems to confirm this.

Comment: @jchl: That may only evaluate to true because libstdc++ adds its own exception specification on top of what's mandated by the standard (but I don't know either way)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a defect to me, though not one I can find in the [active issues list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html) (though #2104 is *similar*).

- Per `[C++11: 20.7.2.2.3/1]`, the assignment is defined to be equivalent to `shared_ptr(r).swap(*this)`;
- But per `[C++11: 20.7.2.2.2]`, `~shared_ptr` itself is not `noexcept`.

Unless I've misunderstood the way in which `noexcept` works, this must be an error.

Alternatively it could simply mean that the assignment operator is only usable when neither the underlying object type nor the deleter type throw on destruction, though even in such a scenario, the lack of any informative note in the standard wording makes me think that this is unlikely.

Comment: Seems like both `operator=` and `~shared_ptr` should be conditionally `noexcept`.

Comment: You can't condition them, because you don't know what the underlying type is of either the deleter or the object.

Comment: @DeadMG The deleter yes, but overriding a noexcept destructor with a throwing one would be an error.

Comment: You know enough about the underlying type of the object, and isn't there a template type argument representing the deleter also?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: it might be unwise, but is it a violation of the standard? If it's not currently forbidden by the standard, and if `shared_ptr` used the noexcept status of the base class destructor to determine its own noexcept status, then `shared_ptr` would have to introduce a requirement that does forbid it for objects managed by `shared_ptr`-to-base-class.

Comment: @SteveJessop §15.4/5: "If a virtual function has an exception-specification, all declarations, including the definition, of any function that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions that are allowed by the exception-specification of the base class virtual function." Noexcept is equivalent to an empty exception-specification. So actually this rules out both deleters and destructors allowing exceptions due to dynamic underlying type.

Comment: Yeah- `shared_ptr` *could* be written to ban throwing deleters and destructors, but it is not. In addition, that assignment operator implementation is not exception safe.

Comment: That "active issues list" link is the core language issues list. This should be be in the [library issues list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html); I cannot find anything there either.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The problem with that is that you would automatically ban using `shared_ptr` with all complex types which are not updated to be `noexcept` destructors.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm talking about conditioning them.

Comment: Right, but in that case, the exception spec is still incorrect.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The `deleter` could still throw even if the object it destroys does not though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The condition would be `noexcept( noexcept( get_deleter()() ) )` not `noexcept( noexcept( get()->~T() ) )`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the isocpp forums, `shared_ptr` simply assumes that the deleter will not throw, and otherwise is UB. This would mean that the real defect is that `shared_ptr`'s destructor is not marked as nothrow.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that `reset()` (without parameters) and `swap` are declared `nothrow` as well.

Also if we take a look at `boost::shared_ptr` it provides the same declarations, except it also declares it's destructor as `never throws` which `std::shared_ptr` for some reason doesn't.

As far as I understand, what it means is not "I guarantee that ~T() will not throw", but "I **prohibit** ~T() to throw and hope you know what you are doing".